# (ios,swift) firebase realtime database can't write when everything is connected

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and trying to write some data to firebase.
My problem is below :
**installed pod 'Firebase/Core'
          pod 'Firebase/Database'** coacopods
and **import Firebase** in Xcode, also changed realtime database rule both **"read" and "write" are true**, everything **is connected** to google firebase, but still can't write data in realtime database? anyone has same problem like me? can anyone help me to fix it?

code 
part one(AppDelegate.swift):
import UIKit
**import Firebase**

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    **FirebaseApp.configure()**

    return true
}
```

part two(ViewController.swift):
import UIKit
**import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase**

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    **let ref = Database.database().reference()**

    **ref.child("someid/name").setValue("mike")**
}
```

}
There is no any error message showing in Xcode or firebase.

Comment: Can you run an HTTP traffic sniffer and see if there is an outgoing request?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your GoogleService-Info.plist by downloading from your console again. This solved my problem.

Comment: How do you think it solved the problem?

Comment: I guess something was wrong with my file. I checked ref, it was correct but **ref.child("someid/name").setValue("mike")** line was doing nothing, added completion to that line but it didn't enter to block. Somehow it worked after changing the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    let value = [
        "name": "mike"
    ] as [String: Any]
    ref.child("someid/name").setValue(value)
}
```